# How to calculate and return the new quantity for an update in DB - NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to calculate and return a `newQty` to pass it for an update in DB. It looks like am getting `NaN` for`newQty`. Let me know what exactly I am doing wrong. Here you will find the console.log :

- `console.log('order type:' + orderType)`order type:Sell
- `console.log('new qty:' + qty)` new qty:300
- `console.log('old qty:' +    typeof oldQty)` old qty:object
- `console.log('old qty:' +    oldQty.toString())` old qty:{
  qtyPorfolio: 500 }
- `console.log('new qty after minus:' + qty)`new qty after
  minus:-300

**JavaScript**

```
const fetchQtyPortfolio = async (arg) => {
  try {
    const query = { symbol: arg.symbol }
    const projection = { _id: 0 }

    const orderType = arg.orderType
    console.log('order type:' + orderType)// Sell

    let qty = arg.qty
    console.log('new qty:' + qty)// 300

    let oldQty = await Portfolio.find(query, projection).select("qtyPorfolio")
    console.log('old qty:' + typeof oldQty)// object
    console.log('old qty:' + oldQty.toString()) // {qtyPorfolio: 500}
    console.log('old qty:' + JSON.stringify(oldQty))//old qty:[{"qtyPorfolio":500}]

    if (isEmpty(oldQty)) {// false
      // Object is empty (Would return true in this example)
      console.log('new qty:' + qty)
      return qty
    } else {
      // Object is NOT empty
      if (orderType === 'Sell') qty = Math.abs(qty) * -1
      console.log('new qty after minus:' + qty)// -300
      const { qtyPorfolio } = oldQty//???
      console.log('qtyPorfolio :' + qtyPorfolio)// undefined
      console.log('qtyPorfolio :' + typeof qtyPorfolio)// undefined
      return newQty = qtyPorfolio + qty// ???
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(`fetchQtyPortfolio error: ${ex}`)
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
exports.postAddTransaction = async (req, res) => {
  const arg = req.body

  const qtyPorfolio = await portfolio.fetchNewQtyPortfolio(arg)
  console.log('quantity portfolio ' + qtyPorfolio)//quantity portfolio NaN

  res.render('buysell')
}
```

**Solution** as per @Amir Wagner I changed find() that was returning array of objects to findOne () that is returning just one object

```
const fetchQtyPortfolio = async (arg) => {
  try {
    const orderType = arg.orderType
    let qty = parseInt(arg.qty)

    const query = { symbol: arg.symbol }
    const projection = { _id: 0 }

    const oldQty = await Portfolio.findOne(query, projection).select("qtyPorfolio")
    //findOne returns the Object{} without the Array
    console.log('old qty:' + typeof oldQty)
    console.log('old qty:' + JSON.stringify(oldQty))

    if (isEmpty(oldQty)) {
      // Object is empty (Would return true in this example)
      return qty
    } else {
      // Object is NOT empty
      if (orderType === 'Sell') qty = Math.abs(qty) * -1
      const { qtyPorfolio } = oldQty
      return newQty = qtyPorfolio + qty
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(`fetchQtyPortfolio error: ${ex}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: To show you what's happening, I edited your question to add the `console.log` results to the code. So if `newQty` is `NaN` it's not happening in the code you've posted. The last line calculates and returns `500 + -300 = 200` so 200 is returned as a promised.

Comment: @DJDaveMark I added the Controller where I am getting the `NaN` console.log

Comment: You need to add more `console.log` statements to show what values you have. Use `JSON.stringify` for objects like `oldQty` instead of `toString()`. And what version of Node are you using? Add a log like this: `console.log(process.version);`

Comment: So the problem is that  - isEmpty(oldQty) returns false while oldQty is an object?

Comment: @DEVCNN looks fine there

Comment: Have you tried JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldQty))?

Comment: @DEVCNN `JSON.stringify` - `[{"qtyPorfolio":500}]`

Comment: @DJDaveMark`JSON.stringify` -  `[{"qtyPorfolio":500}]`. Node version - v11.2.0

Comment: try change  const { qtyPorfolio } = oldQty//??? to  const { qtyPorfolio } = oldQty[0]   
oldQty is an array if you want the object it self work with findOne

Comment: Which ES version do you use? I think the destructuring doesn't work. Change `const qtyPorfolio = oldQty.qtyPorfolio;` if it's an array then use `const qtyPorfolio = oldQty[0].qtyPorfolio;`

Comment: So in the end, your log `old qty:{ qtyPorfolio: 500 }` was [misleading](https://www.softwaretestinggenius.com/photos/1231-1.jpg), which I used to test your code. I'd also suggest using [semicolons](https://hackernoon.com/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding-no-semicolons-82cec422d67d) and using a layered architecture.

Comment: @DJDaveMark actually it was you who led me to the answer. If you post it I will accept it

Comment: @DJDaveMark when you say layered architecture you mean MVC?

Comment: @AmitWagner Pls post your answer because it is the best solution I will up vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since oldQty contains `[{"qtyPorfolio":500}]`, an array, you simply need to access it with:

```
const qtyPorfolio = oldQty[0].qtyPorfolio;
```

If you wanted to use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) (I wouldn't) it would be:

```
const [firstResult] = oldQty
return newQty = firstResult.qtyPorfolio + qty
```

But the far superior solution (which you found yourself) was to use [findOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/index.html) which returns a single document, instead of [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html).

Comment: I just changed find () that was returning array of objects to findOne () that returns just the object

Comment: Yes much better. And if you create a DAO layer, in the end, it would simplify your code. I always create the following layers: presentation (express), service (your business logic), & DAO (mongodb). That way the code the code that does the maths (service) doesn't know about where it comes from (mongodb), it's just an object (your model). If you need to parse/format dates to/from the client, that's the presentation layer's job.

Comment: I am building my first app. I was wondering if you can take a look on my MVC architecture. And give an example of DAO layer. Here is github link https://github.com/forza11879/nodeApp

Comment: I will be offline for the next 24 hours but I will come back to you in regards to your DAO layer suggestion

Comment: @JohnJohn [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DJDaveMark/wjq1f82h/6/) with the layer separation I'd do: Separate layers would be in the own file, but everything related (`portfolio.route.js`, `portfolio.service.js`, `portfolio.dao.js`, `portfolio.test.js`) would all be in a feature folder called portfolio (Folder By Feature). There would be no folders called `dao`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example. I understand now . Here's what the architecture looks like:

`View ---> Controller ---> Service ---> Data Access Layer`
Service/DAO extends those layers to the server side. Web Controller would own multiple Service instances that update the model to fulfill View requests.

The Services will use Model objects to fulfill View requests and persist the outcomes to a database using the data access layer.
The Model is present in all layers in one form or another.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem

```
const { qtyPorfolio } = oldQty
```

Simply do

```
 qtyPorfolio = oldQty[0].qtyPorfolio;
```

Destructuring doesn't work like that. You can fetch the property from an object like that but not from an array. Clearly, your oldQty is an array with one object.

Comment: Agree with you. find() was returning array of objects, so I changed to findOne() that returns just the object